# How to Hide Task Manager's Error Message Dialog Box When Task Manager is Disabled

Tags: java, dialog, taskmanager

Hi i try to make a program with java which must be full screen and always on top. However, when i press CTRL + ALT + DEL task manager comes up. I blocked Task Manager by editing regedit values but now its error message dialog box  "Task Manager has been disabled by your administrator" comes up

How can i hide that dialog box?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible in Java, and in fact I don't know that you can (or want to) do it in general.  The "always on top" layer on Windows contains a stack of windows just like the "user" layer, and you don't normally (and should not) have control over those other programs.  If any one program could take over the entire machine and block anything, even the operating system, from appearing for the user, that would be disturbing...